# Sort a multidimensional array using another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array (hence the order, it is not exactly incremental)

```
array ( 4334 => '4334',
        4335 => '4335',
        4333 => '4333',
        4338 => '4338',
)
```

And this array

```
array ( 
        'alpha' => array ( 4333 => '4333', 'objects' => array ( ), ),
        'bar' => array ( 4338 => '4338', 'objects' => array ( ), ),
        'charlie' => array ( 4334 => '4334', 'objects' => array ( ), 
        'delta' => array ( 4335 => '4335', 'objects' => array ( ), ), ),
)
```

As we can see, the second array contains 4 arrays. Inside there is an id again, e.g. `alpha` has `4333`. How can I sort the second array, whereas the order is the same as the first plain array by id?

The final ordering should be:

```
array (
        'charlie' => array ( 4334 => '4334', 'objects' => array ( ),
        'delta' => array ( 4335 => '4335', 'objects' => array ( ), ), ),
        'alpha' => array ( 4333 => '4333', 'objects' => array ( ), ),
        'bar' => array ( 4338 => '4338', 'objects' => array ( ), ),
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP sort a multidimensional array by another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470894/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-another-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
function elementScore($element, $sorting_array)
{
    // get the first element and find its position in the sorting array.
    return $sorting_array[intval(array_values($element)[0])];
}

$array1 = array ( 4334 => '4334',
    4335 => '4335',
    4333 => '4333',
    4338 => '4338',
);
// get the values without the keys and flip keys and values.
$sorting_array = array_flip(array_values($array1));

$array2 = array (
    'alpha' => array ( 4333 => '4333', 'objects' => array ( ), ),
    'bar' => array ( 4338 => '4338', 'objects' => array ( ), ),
    'charlie' => array ( 4334 => '4334', 'objects' => array ( ),
        'delta' => array ( 4335 => '4335', 'objects' => array ( ), ), ),
);

// sort based on the score function.
uasort($array2, function ($a, $b) use (&$sorting_array) {
    return elementScore($a, $sorting_array) > elementScore($b, $sorting_array);
});
```